# How to make use of the text file chosen and upload to solaris?

Tags: php, html, mysql, solaris

I am currently using a combination of HTML, MySql, and PHP using Solaris as a server. I had created the tables on MySql, and needed to use Html to upload a file from my PC desktop to the server's folder.

The 1st button is used to select the file
The 2nd button is used to load the data to the HQ database
The 3rd button is used to jump to another php file.

I got 2 queries, firstly, what is the code to use the data from the selected textfile to load up to the database. Secondly, how do i jump to another directory with the 3rd button?

```
<h2> Upload HQ WareHouse</h2>

//upload file function
<form method ="post" action="checkTransaction.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name ="datatxtfile" id ="datatxtfile">
    <input type="submit" value= "Click here to Upload The Transaction's File into the Database">
</form>

<br>

<input type="button" name="a" value= "Click here to return " onclick ="hist()">
</body>


//PHP code to explode
<?php


 $file = file_get_contents("Inventory_1000.txt");
 //var_dump($file);

 $lines = explode("\n",$file);

 print_r($lines); print line

 foreach($lines as $index => $line) {
  $data = explode(":", $line);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO wareHouse (
        productName, categoty, manufacturer, barcode, buyingPrice, currentStock, minimumStock) 
        VALUES 
        '". $data[0] ."',
        '". $data[1] . "',
        '". $data[2] ."',
        '". $data[3] . "',
        '". $data[4] ."',
        '". $data[5] . "',
        '". $data[6] . "'
       )") or die(mysql_error());

 }

?>
```

===============================================

## UPDATED

To clarify,

I am trying to select a dynamic .txt file from a location in a directory on the PC through PHP, HTML and load up to an online database mySQL on solaris, so I cant use the syntax .txt to load up into the database.

The bottom is just an example code how i use an example .txt file onto mySQL since I am not sure how to select a dynamic .txt.

Hence, the operation is as follow:
1) First button will choose a .txt file from directory

2) Second button will be upload the data to mySQL, assuming .txt file is compatible and not 
corrupted

3) 3rd button allow the user to return the other page after uploading of files is done

May i ask how do i get it done since i intend to create a dynamic .txt file name?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: As stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Answer (score 0):

1. > what is the code to use the data from the selected textfile to load up to the database.

   Why not just use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html)?

   ```sql
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'Inventory_1000.txt' INTO TABLE wareHouse
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'
   LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
   (
     productName,
     categoty,
     manufacturer,
     barcode,
     buyingPrice,
     currentStock,
     minimumStock
   )
   ```
2. > how do i jump to another directory with the 3rd button?

   Either use a hyperlink instead (recommended), or else the `onclick` event should set `location.href` with the URI of the resource you want to be loaded.